# Need help in evaluating a Definite Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am stuck at this definite integral
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}  \frac{1}{1-(\sin x)(\cos y)}\, dx . 
$$
I tried multiplying and dividing by $cosx$ and then using by parts integration, but I not able to proceed further .Someone please help me out .

Comment: Hint: Use Weierstrass substitution.

Comment: $\cos(y)$ is just a constant in this case so call it say $\alpha$ then use Weierstrauss substitution as others have suggested and you should get it pretty quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Try using the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) ( $\tan{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}=t$).

You will be left with the following integral $$\int_0^1 \frac{2}{t^2-2t\cos{y}+1} \; \mathrm{d}t=\int_0^1 \frac{2}{\left(t-\cos{y}\right)^2+\sin^2y} \; \mathrm{d}t$$